# Debugging error 000539 from ArcGIS Field Calculator?

Tags: arcpy, field-calculator, python-parser, error-000539

What am I doing wrong in this field calculator logic?

Pre-logic

```
def re_score(elev_t,f2, contour):
 f2=contour
 if elev_t.endswith('.5'):
  f2 = "Midi"
 return f2
```

Expression for field "Contourtyp"

```
 re_score(!Elev_t!,f2,!Contourtyp!)
```

I just want to rename the contour type where the contours are at half meter intervals. The 'Elev_T' is a text column with all the elevations (converted to text as I couldn't think of a way to do it with numerical elevation data which has .25, .5, 75 and 1m intervals). I want all .5 called 'midi' and .25/.75 remain as 'minor' and 1m remains as 'basic'

> Executing (Calculate Field (3)): CalculateField 328000_8123000
>   Contourtyp " re_score(!Elev_t!,f2,!Contourtyp!)" PYTHON_9.3 "def
>   re_score(elev_t,f2, contour):\n f2=contour\n if
>   elev_t.endswith('.5'):\n  f2 = "Midi"\n return f2" Start Time: Thu Apr
>   12 17:10:40 2012 ERROR 000539: :
>   unexpected indent (, line 1) Failed to execute (Calculate
>   Field (3)). Failed at Thu Apr 12 17:10:40 2012 (Elapsed Time: 0.00
>   seconds)

I have tried different indentation and no luck...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

```
def re_score(elev_t, contour):
        if elev_t.endswith('.5'):
            return "Midi"
        else:
            return contour
```

and then:
Countourtyp =

```
re_score(!Elev_t!, !Contourtyp!)
```